# stream_resolve_include_path returning false?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-form2

I have a fieldset that is implementing `InputFilterProviderInterface`. My `getInputFilterSpecification` function looks like this:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
    $validator = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension([
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'gif',
    ]);
    return [
        [
            'name' => 'logo',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => [
                $validator,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

As you can guess, I am trying to validate the file upload by extension.

My problem is that the validator is giving the error message

> File is not readable or does not exist

Looking into the `Extension` class I found the function that's causing the issue: `stream_resolve_include_path($file)`. When I `var_dump` `$file` I get the following output:

> C:\Windows\Temp\php6BE7.tmp

So... Why is `stream_resolve_include_path` failing to resolve this path? How do I fix it?

This is currently running on a Windows Virtual Machine. Is this part of the problem? i.e. the above function only works on compatible operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short term solution - extend the validator and overwrite the `isValid` function.

Find the line:

`if (empty($file) || false === stream_resolve_include_path($file)) {`

and replace it with:

`if (empty($file) || false === is_file($file)) {`